# Not all docker containers are starting on server startup/reboot

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

We have Ubuntu servers that automatically run Docker on startup and in the docker compose the containers have restart: always. One containers depends on the other 2 and this is the one that doesn't boot up correctly. If I run docker-compose restart it does show as running.

When I run docker-compose logs control-php> they are empty.

`docker-compose ps` on startup results in:

```
control-php   docker-php-entrypoint /hom ...   Exit 127
db            docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up         3306/tcp
redis         docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up         6379/tcp
```

control-php depends on db and redis (which are both running). I did try introducing health_checks on db and redis and adding them to the depends on for control-php but this didn't seem to change anything. In fact, when I ran docker-compose ps I could see the db and control-php condition was running. After sometime they became healthy but web and control-php still showed as 'Exit 127'.

Here's my docker-compose config:

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        container_name: db
        image: mariadb:10.3.4
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: control
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    redis:
        container_name: redis
        image: redis:3.2.11
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - redis_data:/data
    control-php:
        container_name: control-php
        image: livebuzzevents/php:e4d22a4
        environment:
            - APP_ENV
            - NODE
            - REDIS_CLIENT="predis"
            - REDIS_HOST="redis"
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - /home/livebuzz/code/control:/var/www/control
            - /home/livebuzz/onsite-setup/control/crontab:/home/crontab
            - /home/livebuzz/onsite-setup/control/nuke-locks.php:/home/nuke-locks.php
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
volumes:
  db_data:
  redis_data:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: If I was going to guess, I'd hypothesize that Docker itself (not Compose) is restarting the containers at startup time, and therefore not seeing the `depends_on:` constraints.  What's in the logs of the two failed containers?  Can you reduce the Compose setup to a [mcve] with the minimum containers and settings required to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response. I've updated the description with this. If I run docker-compose logs there is nothing in there. If I do docker-compose restart and then check the logs it has an entry that it is running